# Is it possible to convert hex format character back to decimal in a CL program?

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

I have a RPG program A and a CL program B. A calls B with a data structure as entry parameter. This data structure contains characters as well as packed decimals. The entry parameter in B is declared as a character variable, so when the entry parameter is passed in from A, the decimal values end up in their hex-decimal format. I need their original decimal values in B. Is there any way to convert these hex character strings back to decimal in B?

Comment: Side note:  This is not quite hex format since the low order half byte (aka nibble) represents the sign rather than a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert.  Define the decimal field over the appropriate location in your data structure.

```
PGM (&STRUCT)
   DCL &STRUCT      *CHAR 12
   DCL &NAME        *CHAR 10   STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&STRUCT)
   DCL &NBR         *DEC (3 0) STG(*DEFINED) DEFVAR(&STRUCT 11)
```

The *DEFINED storage method works well when the position is fixed.  In a situation where the location may vary, then use *BASED storage.

In this example there is a numeric value in a position determined by a format parameter.  The value will be incremented by 1 or two.

```
PGM (&STRUCT)
   DCL &STRUCT     *CHAR 80
   DCL &FMT        *CHAR 4
   DCL &P1         *PTR
   DCL &NUM        *DEC (3 0) STG(*BASED)
   ...
   CHGVAR &FMT %SUBSTR(&STRUCT 1 4)
   CHGVAR  &P1  %ADDRESS(&STRUCT)
   SELECT
      WHEN (&FMT = 'ONE ')  THEN(DO)
         CHGVAR %OFFSET(&P1) 20       /* POS 21 IN STRUCT */
         CHGVAR &NUM (&NUM + 1)       /* INCREMENT NUMBER BY 1 */
         ENDDO
      WHEN  (&FMT = 'TWO ')  THEN(DO)
         CHGVAR %OFFSET(&P1) 40       /* POS 41 IN STRUCT */
         CHGVAR &NUM (&NUM + 2)       /* INCREMENT NUMBER BY 2 */
         ENDDO
      OTHERWISE DO
         /* EXIT WITH ERROR */
         ...
         ENDDO
      ENDSELECT
```

See [Variables in CL commands](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frbam6%2Fworkv.htm)

Comment: Suppose there is another RPG program C which also calls B, but passing a different data structure as parameter. If both are declared in B, is it going to cause any trouble? Depending on the caller program the decimal value might get assigned with a non decimal value. I am not sure if this works.

Comment: Yes that would definitely be a problem for almost any called program, if it is unable to determine the format of its input data, and thus unable to determine how to properly process it. Often you will find that it has been designed with some method of identifying the input format. As I said above, if the location of your decimal value is variable, then based storage is often the best choice.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it without using DCL? Still this is not a very flexible choice.

Comment: Actually, the based storage concept is very dynamic, overlaying your variable definition over whatever part of variable memory you wish, just by setting the address of the pointer. What more flexibility do you need, and why?

Comment: As I described before, there might be more that one program calling B, and they are likely to pass different data structures as entry parameter. So if it is mapped to the wrong type of memory due to different data structure passed in, would there be any problem?

Comment: So exactly how will you know the location of the packed decimal value in this data structure?

Comment: If necessary, a second parameter might be used to indicate what is the caller program so B knows what would be the passed in data structure.

Comment: Answer edited to give an example showing how &NUM can overlay different position in the structure.